# Can't build Rustless on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, rust

I'm trying to build the rustless ["basic usage" sample project](https://github.com/rustless/rustless#basic-usage).

This is my Cargo.toml. I had to add the dependencies in Cargo.toml in order to avoid the build error `error[E0463]: can't find crate for 'hyper'`

```
[package]
name = "rustlessTest"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["x"]

[dependencies.rustless]
git = "https://github.com/rustless/rustless"

[dependencies]
hyper = "0.9.14"
iron = "0.4.0"
rustc-serialize = "0.3.22"
valico = "1.0.1"
```

I also downloaded the OpenSSL library & sources. I stored them under `C:\OpenSSL\lib and C:\OpenSSL\include` and set the directories as a environment variable, as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/305ih7/using_hyper_on_windows/) about how to using Hyper on Windows.

When I try to compile, it fails with the following output:

```
Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl v0.7.14`
....
....
```

Comment: Use `cargo -vv build` to get more info.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to build OpenSSL on Windows by following [the solution from this blog post](https://facility9.com/2016/03/installing-rust-on-windows/).

Here's a summary:

1. Download Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1u from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Install it with default settings.
2. Set the following environment variables

   ```
   DEP_OPENSSL_INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include
   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include
   OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC
   OPENSSL_LIBS=ssleay32MT:libeay32MT
   ```
3. Install Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio Code with C++ support.
4. Ensure that all path variables are set correctly
5. Set `rust-msvc` as the toolchain. You can check this by typing `rustup show` into the console. You should get an output like this:

   ```
   Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

   stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
   rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)
   ```

Now you should able to build Rust projects which requires OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it is because OpenSSL is not found. A good tutorial is in the README of [rust-openssl](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl).

> #### Windows MSVC
>
> On MSVC it's unfortunately not always a trivial process acquiring
>   OpenSSL. Perhaps the easiest way to do this right now is to download
>   [precompiled binaries](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and install them on your system. Currently it's
>   recommended to install the 1.1.0 (non-light) installation if you're
>   choosing this route.
>
> Once a precompiled binary is installed you can configure this crate to
>   find the installation via an environment variable:
>
> ```
> set OPENSSL_DIR=C:\OpenSSL-Win64
> ```
>
> Note that this OpenSSL distribution does not ship with any root
>   certificates. So to make requests to servers on the internet, you have
>   to install them manually. Download the [cacert.pem file from here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html),
>   copy it somewhere safe (`C:\OpenSSL-Win64\certs` is a good place) and
>   point the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable there:
>
> ```
> set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem
> ```
>
> After that, you're just a `cargo build` away!
>
> #### Windows GNU (MinGW)
>
> The easiest way to acquire OpenSSL when working with MinGW is to
>   ensure you're using [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io) and to then
>   execute:
>
> ```
> # 32-bit pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-openssl
>
> # 64-bit pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl
> ```
>
> And after that, a `cargo build` should be all you need!
>
> #### Manual configuration
>
> rust-openssl's build script will by default attempt to locate OpenSSL
>   via pkg-config or other system-specific mechanisms. This will not work
>   in some situations however, for example cross compiling or when using
>   a copy of OpenSSL other than the normal system install.
>
> The build script can be configured via environment variables:
>
> - `OPENSSL_DIR` - If specified, a directory that will be used to find   OpenSSL installation. It's expected that under this directory the
>     `include`   folder has header files and a `lib` folder has the runtime
>     libraries.
> - `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR` - If specified, a directory that will be used to find   OpenSSL libraries. Overrides the `lib` folder implied by
>     `OPENSSL_DIR`   (if specified).
> - `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` - If specified, a directory that will be used to find   OpenSSL header files. Overrides the `include` folder implied
>     by `OPENSSL_DIR`   (if specified).
> - `OPENSSL_STATIC` - If specified, OpenSSL libraries will be statically rather   than dynamically linked.
>
> If `OPENSSL_DIR` is specified, then the build script will skip the
>   pkg-config step.

It's a nightmare; OpenSSL with Windows is really painful. I hope that one day Rust has its own implementation of SSL/TLS.